# i can't assign a role to an user, via my code

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  name: "manuallyverify",
  description: "Manually verifies an User.",

  limits: {
    owner: false,
    permission: ["MANAGE_ROLES"],
    cooldown: "10s",
  },

  options: [
    {
      name: "user",
      description: "The User that will be affected by this action.",
      type: 6,
      required: true,
    }
  ],

  run: (client, interaction) => {
    let member = interaction.options.getUser("user").toString()
    let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == process.env.verified_role_id)
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(":white_check_mark: ・ Manually Verified the User.")
      .addFields(
        {
          name: "User affected",
          value: interaction.options.getUser("user").toString(),
          inline: true,
        },

        {
          name: "Role given",
          value: `${role}`,
          inline: true,
        }
      )
      .setColor("#95eda4");

    try {
      interaction.guild.member.roles.cache.add(role)
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch (e) {
      interaction.reply({content:`I encountered an error: ${e}`, ephemeral: true});
    }

  },
};
```

so, this is my code, i'm making a simple verification bot that will be a template on github , but when i run the command, it gives me this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

so, i guess the error is because something is undefinited between interaction.guild, or guild.member. i didnt code for a while so i'm probably missing / forgetting something
also, sorry if my framework is bad

edit: i got this code to work thanks to a guy in the comments, so, thanks for coming here and have a good day

Comment: `guild.member` is `undefined`

Comment: Please do not post code nor errors in images, post the text itself. Secondly, read the error, don't ignore it. Get in the habit of reading errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any property called `interaction.guild.member` and I assume what you are trying to do is to add the role to the user provided. Therefore, what you could do is use `interaction.options.getMember("user")` to get the user in the option and then add the role to that `GuildMember`. A small example:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  name: "manuallyverify",
  description: "Manually verifies an User.",

  limits: {
    owner: false,
    permission: ["MANAGE_ROLES"],
    cooldown: "10s",
  },

  options: [
    {
      name: "user",
      description: "The User that will be affected by this action.",
      type: 6,
      required: true,
    }
  ],

  run: (client, interaction) => {
    let memberToAddRole = interaction.options.getMember("user")
    let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == process.env.verified_role_id)
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(":white_check_mark: ・ Manually Verified the User.")
      .addFields(
        {
          name: "User affected",
          value: memberToAddRole.user.toString(),
          inline: true,
        },

        {
          name: "Role given",
          value: `${role}`,
          inline: true,
        }
      )
      .setColor("#95eda4");

    try {
      memberToAddRole.roles.cache.add(role)
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch (e) {
      interaction.reply({content:`I encountered an error: ${e}`, ephemeral: true});
    }

  },
};
```

Note: the code you provided was a bit inefficient and redundant in some parts, so I have changed that accordingly

Comment: that worked. thank you so much mate, i haven't touch code in a while so i was a bit confused. thank you again for your collaboration.

Answer (score -1):

The error message tells you *exactly* where and what your issues is. The error message indicates that `roles` is undefined, so either `interaction.guild.roles` or `interaction.guild.member.roles` is undefined.